# How to handle html back in webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am using webview to show one html page in this page i have one button, through this button click i am navigating to another webpage, on that webpage have one hyperlink for go back but when i try with this code

```
<a href="#backButton" onclick="window.history.back();">Go back</a>
```

but not able to show previous page so, please suggest me can i get any event of hyperlink on my activity or any other suggestion to show previous page without pressing back button of device

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue with replace with

```
<a href="#backButton" onclick="window.history.back();">Go back</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#backButton" onclick="window.history.back();return false">Go back</a>
```

now its works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code mentioned below:

**WAY-1**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                mWebView.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**WAY-2**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
        mWebView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

hope it will help you... !!!

Comment: I dont want to use device back button  through hyper link please see my code of back button which i have edited

Comment: i have placed my html code of back link, i have tried this code on mozilla browser and it get back to previous page but not working on webview